# How to convolve a periodic signal with an aperiodic signal?

Tags: convolution, dirichlet-convolution, deconvolution

Basically, when there are two periodic signals, say x(t) and h(t) which are to be convolved, then convolution is carried out over a range of their common time period (which is equal to the least common factor of the time periods of both).

If either x(t) or h(t) is aperiodic, then it can be assumed that the aperiodic signal's time period is infinite, hence the common time period to both the signals to be convolved is also infinite which implies that in such case, aperiodic convolution is to be performed which integrates over the entire domain.
When both x(t) and h(t) are aperiodic, then obviously, aperiodic convolution is needed. But if suppose x(t) is aperiodic and h(t) is periodic with period T, then how to handle the convolution?

**Can we take one single cycle of periodic h(t) and regard this as aperiodic h'(t) and then calculate aperiodic convolution between h'(t) and x(t)?**

Will the answer be correct?